# RWops undefined references

Tags: c++, c

I would like to make a graphical text in my opengl program so I downloaded this `2D font renderer` [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/oglbmfont). It's a C source and I would like to translate it in C++ and change most of its implementation. However, compiling it in g++ after turning .c into .cpp files gets me in this undefined references in `RWops.lib`. Maybe the `RWops.lib` I have is not suitable for C++ and I cannot find this lib file in the internet. How can I resolve this linker errors?

```
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\MinGW\include  -o bin\Debug\BMfont.exe obj\Debug\BMFtest.o obj\Debug\oglBMFont.o obj\Debug\oglfont.o   -lOpenGL32 -lGLfwdll C:\Users\Mark\Documents\CodeBlocks\BMFont\RWops.lib  C:\Users\Mark\Documents\CodeBlocks\BMFont\RWops.lib C:\Users\Mark\Documents\CodeBlocks\BMFont\RWops.lib 
obj\Debug\oglBMFont.o: In function `Z8bmf_loadP7bm_fontPc':
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/BMfont/oglBMFont.cpp:77: undefined reference to `RWFromFile(char const*, char const*)'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/BMfont/oglBMFont.cpp:80: undefined reference to `RWskipline(RWops*)'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/BMfont/oglBMFont.cpp:84: undefined reference to `RWsscanf(RWops*, char*, ...)'
C:/Users/Mark/Documents/CodeBlocks/BMfont/oglBMFont.cpp:104: undefined reference to `RWsscanf(RWops*, char*, ...)'
```

I'm using `MinGW` through `Code::Blocks`

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: You (i.e. the headers) need to declare those functions "extern C". The names which the C++ compiler/linker use internally are funny and not compatible with the C function names used internally. (I assume that you actually downloaded RWops.lib and did not translate it yourself).

Comment: You can see what's in the lib and what your program references e.g. with a suitable objdump command (I assume mingw comes with an objdump).